# Custom time interval infinitely looping

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a custom interval to render only the ticks I want in a d3 time scale. I can partially achieve this like so:

```
const customInterval = d3.timeMonth.filter(date => {
  return d3.timeMonth.count(0, date) % 2 === 0;
});
```

I can then use this with my axis:

```
axis.ticks(customInterval)
```

In this case I'm rendering a tick every odd month. The problem comes when I want limit the ticks based on known date(s). For example, I may want to render ticks only after a date like 2020/03/01. So taking the same approach, I do something like:

```
const customInterval = d3.timeMonth.filter(date => {
  return date > moment('2020/03/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD').toDate();
});
```

The code above results in an infinite loop. In this case I'm using moment but the same behaviour can be observed without the use of moment.

How can I filter out ticks with a custom interval based on specific times?

*Reproduction here: https://codepen.io/garethdn/pen/NWNYzgN*

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know why there will be infinite loop. I consoled the `date` and it will start from 2020 to "Fri Jun 01 -1379".

But you can render the date using `tickValues`, See [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues).

> If a values array is specified, the specified values are used for ticks rather than using the scale’s automatic tick generator.

```
axis.tickValues(scale.ticks().filter(d=>{
    return d > cutOffDate;
}))
.tickFormat(d => moment(d).format('MMM'))
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/83d9aoLg/)

**Without using tickValues**

1. generate ticks as usual
2. remove those before the `cutOffDate`

   ```
    axisSelection
    .attr('transform', "translate(0, 50)")
    .call(axis)
    .call(g=>{
        g.selectAll(".tick")
            .each(function(d) {
            if(d < cutOffDate) {
                d3.select(this).remove()
            }
          })
    });
   ```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uhcsrpyv/6)

Comment: The library I'm using is an abstraction of d3 and for my use case I need to generate the ticks using `d3.ticks` not `d3.tickValues`

Comment: @garethdn You can render all the ticks and then remove those before the `cutOffDate`. https://jsfiddle.net/uhcsrpyv/6/